# Get characters after the third forward slash ("/") - using regex

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to get the substring, after the third forward slash ("`/`") from a string.

http://www.google.com/search?q=Regular+Expressions while stopping before ? and # if they are present in the string.

I have the regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(":\\/\\/[0-9a-zA-Z-\\.:]+(\\/)([^?#]*)$");
```

however it doesn't work with every string

I also came up with the regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(.*)?:\\/\\/[^#?]*);
```

however this one grabs everything before the third forward slash ("`/`").

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Show sample output for both cases (# and ?)

Comment: When you say "doesn't work with every string", please show what you tested

Comment: Also, do you really need regex? `indexOf` and `substring` probably work well enough

Comment: With the string "https://www.google.com/hello?test#", it should just grab the /hello avoiding the ? and the # characters. I have tested with these string https://www.google.com/hello

"https://www.google.com/search?q=Regular+Expressions&num=1000"
"https://google.com:80/#". It works partially with the last string only when the # is removed

Comment: there are not even 3 `/` in there :)

Comment: @beronsus - You need the `/` as well?

Comment: Sorry...I meant the string http:// google.com/hello#test#. My mistakes. the "http://" removed itself when I posted!

Comment: @TheLostMind - yes, it would help to have the /

Comment: @beronsus - Your question says "after the third /". :(

Comment: You don't have to include the "/", as It can simply be concatenated. My apologies!

Comment: @beronsus - Anyways, changed my original answer to make it work as you expect it to :).

Comment: Better to use `URL` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will work in java :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "http://www.google.com/search?q=Regular+Expressions";
    String regex = "(?:.*?/){2}.*?(/\\w+)(\\?|#).*"; // Don't capture anything upto the 3rd "/" then capture everything until you get a "?" or a "#" and then don't capture the rest. Replace everything with the captured value
    String str = s.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
    System.out.println(str);
    String s2 = "https://www.google.com/hello?test#";
    String str2 = s2.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
    System.out.println(str2);

}
```

O/P :

```
/search
/hello
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
(?:.*?\/){3}([^\/?#]+)
```

or in java

```
(?:.*?\\/){3}([^\\/?#]+)
```

(escaped backslashes).

It **matches** anything up to, and including, a slash - three times. Then **captures** everything up to, **not** including, a slash, question mark or hash sign.

Result is in capture group 1.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6QqHwf/1).